# cann't connect to the mysql docker container following the official instructures

Tags: mysql, docker

Following steps in https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/:

> > Start a mysql server instance
>
> Starting a MySQL instance is simple:
>
> $ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d
> mysql:tag
>
> ... where some-mysql is the name you want to assign to your container,
> my-secret-pw is the password to be set for the MySQL root user and tag
> is the tag specifying the MySQL version you want. See the list above
> for relevant tags. Connect to MySQL from the MySQL command line client
>
> The following command starts another mysql container instance and runs
> the mysql command line client against your original mysql container,
> allowing you to execute SQL statements against your database instance:
>
> $ docker run -it --network some-network --rm mysql mysql -hsome-mysql
> -uexample-user -p
>
> ... where some-mysql is the name of your original mysql container
> (connected to the some-network Docker network).

I started a mysql docker container, and then I tried to run another as the mysql client, but I don't know how to specific the --network parameter:

What should I input instead of `some-network`?  I am newbie to Docker, and have no idea of `Docker network`. If I ommit this parameter, `Unknown MySQL server host`  error is given.

Answer (score 1):

*Before you start the first container*, you need to create a Docker network

```sh
docker network create some-network
```

You can use any name you want here, but I will use `some-network` for consistency with the question.

When you start the database container, it also needs to be attached to the same network

```sh
docker volume create mysql-data  # this is essentially required too
docker run \
  --name some-mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw \
  -d \
  --net some-network \                 # matches `docker network create`
  -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/data \  # don't lose data on restart
  mysql:tag
```

(There is also a [`docker network connect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_connect/) command, but recreating containers to change settings is a pretty normal practice.)

You also don't need a second container to run a MySQL client: you can connect with the ordinary `mysql` command-line tool from the host.  You need to publish a port out of the container

```sh
docker run \
  -p 12345:3306 \
  ...
```

The first port number can be anything you want that doesn't conflict with another process on the host; the second number must be the standard MySQL port number 3306.  You can then connect to that database with

```sh
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -u example-user -p
```

Other answers to this question have endorsed Docker Compose as a setup.  Compose will `docker network create` a network for you; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes this setup in more detail.  However, it's not great at running interactive terminal applications, and you might need to do something like `docker-compose run db mysql -h db ...` to get access to it this way.  The published `ports:` approach will work too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one container which work together, you should read about docker-compose in order to config network, host, env var and so on...

```yaml
// docker-compose.yml

version: "3.2"

services:
  mysql_client:
    depends_on:
      - mysql_database

  mysql_database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

```sh
# exec this command to up your containers
docker-compose up
```

By default container are on the same network, in your `mysql_client` use `mysql_database` as hostname for mysql connection.

Answer (score 0):

Via [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer) I found this docker compose script to have Adminer and MySQL running in harmony.

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials

version: '3.1'

services:

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Save it ti a file called `docker-compose.yml` and run it using docker-compose.

In cmd promt navigate to the directory containing the file and run the following:
`docker-compose up`

[docker-compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)